# How can i print a reversed NumPy array with the element type float

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy

def arrays(arr):
    # complete this function
    # use numpy.array

arr = input().strip().split(' ')
result = arrays(arr)
print(result)
```

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([0,1,2,5,6],float)
print a
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np
arr = input().strip().split(' ')
def arrays(arr):
    arr = np.array(arr, dtype=float)
    return(arr[::-1]) # this will reverse the array
arrays(arr)
```